# wordpress上でのアコーディオンが動かない

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress

**前提・実現したいこと**
webサイト上でのアコーディオン実装

**発生している問題・エラーメッセージ**
質問をクリックするとその答えがスライドして表示/非表示されるはずが、
なぜかそうならないのです。

どういじれば、動きますか？

**該当のソースコード**

htmlファイル

```
 <div class="container">
            <div class="accordion">
                <div class="accordion-container">
                    <h4 class="accordion-title jsAccordionTitle">Engressはサラリーマンでも学習を続けられるでしょうか？</h4>
                    <div class="accordion-content">Engressは各個人に最適な学習プランをご提供しております。サラリーマンの方でも継続できます。</div>
                    <h4 class="accordion-title jsAccordionTitle">教材はオリジナルのものを使用しているのでしょうか？</h4>
                    <div class="accordion-content">Engressは各個人に最適な学習プランをご提供しております。サラリーマンの方でも継続できます。</div>
                    <h4 class="accordion-title jsAccordionTitle">講師に日本人はいますか？</h4>
                    <div class="accordion-content">Engressは各個人に最適な学習プランをご提供しております。サラリーマンの方でも継続できます。</div>
                    <h4 class="accordion-title jsAccordionTitle">TOEFL以外の海外大学合格のサポートもしてもらえるのでしょうか？</h4>
                    <div class="accordion-content">Engressは各個人に最適な学習プランをご提供しております。サラリーマンの方でも継続できます。</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JSファイル

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.accordion-title').click(function() {
        $('.accordion-content').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

下記でどうでしょう。

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.accordion-content').hide()
    $('.accordion-title').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```